# Grease Pencil Clipping Through Objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil

I've been using the grease pencil to create lines around my objects in Blender 8.2 with Cycles.  I'm really happy with the results for the most part,  but I'm having problems with some of the lines clipping through my meshes.  It seems to happen most often in areas that also have grease pencil lines.

If you look at the picture below, you'll notice that you can see the white grease pencil lines of the bottom of the dresser clipping through on the green lines.  The problem is also particularly present in the bottom left corner.  This worsens when the blur effect is applied.  Without the Blur effect, I still have problems as seen in the bottom left corner of the dresser, but I do not experience the problems with the white clipping through to the green areas until the blur filter is applied.

I've tried switching the stroke depth order between 2D and 3D layers and the problem is still there.  I've tried moving the lines around and that doesn't seem to help either. Are there other options I should look into?

[image: Clipping]